# I’m trying to find a book I read about 10 years ago about a poor or orphaned boy

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

This book was about a young boy who went to an academy of magic I think, the most vivid part I remember is he could also make things at a smithy, and he made his friends wolf medallions. I know he was either really poor or an orphan and he made friends with a boy at the school who was the son of a lord or something, really wealthy.

Comment: Welcome to SF&F!  This is a good start to an id question.    Please note that the more information you give us, the more likely we are to be able to identify it.   Take a look at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/59154 for some hints which might jog your memory or help you think of things to add that you might not think are useful.

Comment: Possibly it might be part of the "Circle of Magic" series by Tamora Pierce? One of the students "Daja" is an orphan who specialty is Smithing Magic.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_Magic You can check it out and see if this is what you remember. I have never read it so don't know how well it fits your description.

Comment: As a side note, if it were the "Circle of Magic" books by Pierce, it would be two girls. Briar, with his plant magic, is the only male of the group. However, it does have Daja, a smith, and Sandry, a noble, among the main cast.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much for your responses! I’ve actually read all the Tamaora pierce series (and love them!), but definitely not those ones, but thank you - I feel like it was a really random and obscure one I found - I think he had a mentor as well and maybe he crafted a sword towards the end and the wolf medallion thing was right towards the end of the book! I’m really struggling to remember particulars as I have read so many books but yeah maybe some one will know! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

*[The Novice](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25901556-the-novice)*, by Taran Matharu, matches on most of your points.

[image: Front cover of The Novice]

> When blacksmith apprentice Fletcher discovers that he has the ability to summon demons from another world, he travels to Vocans Adept Military Academy. There, the gifted are trained in the art of summoning. Fletcher is put through grueling training as a battlemage to fight in the Hominum Empire’s war against Orcs. He must tread carefully while training alongside children of powerful nobles. The power hungry, those seeking alliances, and the fear of betrayal surround him. Fletcher finds himself caught in the middle of powerful forces, with only his demon Ignatius for help.
>
> As the pieces on the board maneuver for supremacy, Fletcher must decide where his loyalties lie. The fate of an empire is in his hands. The Novice is the first in a trilogy about Fletcher, his demon Ignatius, and the war against the Orcs.

That said, I haven't found any mention of him forging wolf medallions yet. It's also a little earlier than ten years ago, having been published in 2015 (although I've also seen references to this originally being a Wattpad story, which could be where you read it ten years ago).

Comment: Thank you FuzzyBoots! I don’t think this is the one though I have just bought it and am looking forward to reading it! I scanned it quickly but I don’t think there was any different races in the book I’m thinking of, but really appreciate you putting me on to this! :)

Comment: @kab: Ah sorry it's not the one just yet. If this did being up new details like there being certain fantasy races, please edit those details into your question. This dialogue is how we improve.:)